# SSH shell prompt does not show user@host for one user

Tags: ssh, users

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server running. I created user1 when I installed, and created user2 today with '1useradd' and I added it to all the same groups as user1.

But when I log in remotely using SSH, the prompt for user1 looks like this:

```
user1@host:~$
```

And the prompt for user2 looks like this:

```
$
```

Most importantly, the shell doesn't behave as nicely as I'm used to when I'm  logged in as user2. There is no autocomplete of commands or files with tab, and I can't access the MRU with up.

Comment: Between `adduser` and `useradd` I always use `adduser`, it is the recommended "high level" routine, which also can/will create useful defaults for the new user, whereas `useradd` only generates the user and does nothing else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because their shell is set to /bin/sh, and not /bin/bash. You can use the program `chsh` (CHange SHell) to change that user's shell. When you're logged in as that user, run:

```
chsh /bin/bash
```

I would recommend against editing /etc/passwd manually as you could accidentally enter a syntactically wrong line in to it (without realising), which might break logins for other users.

Comment: I noticed that in /etc/passwd the entries look like:
user1:x:1000:1000:user1,,,:/home/user1/bin/bash
user2:x:1001:1001::/home/user2:bin/sh

Do you know what the user1,,, does? csh didn't seem to change that part.

Comment: The comma-separated stuff is called Gecos data. It's used for things like room number, telephone number, and some other things. Running adduser actually prompts you for all of this info, but it's largely useless for you if this is just your personal computer.
Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Password_file) wiki link for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Use the method in the update, it's safer than manually editing passwd file.

the `useradd` command apparently sets `/bin/sh` as the default shell (which in turn is linked to `/bin/dash`). Try editing `/etc/passwd` and change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` for user2.

In the future, use `adduser` instead.

**UDPATE:**
As @Scott suggested below, instead of editing `/etc/passwd` use the chsh command:

`chsh /bin/bash`

Source: http://the-hydra.blogspot.com.ar/2012/03/useradd-and-adduser-are-same-think.html

Comment: That did it! So funny that useradd and adduser both exist.

Comment: What @Scott says is true. I forgot the `chsh` command. One should always try to avoid editing system files directly if there's a command that does that for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While `chsh` gets the job done, just like one would modify several other aspects of a user, the `usermod` command is your friend:

`usermod -s /bin/bash user`

It is the editing counterpart of `useradd`.

Answer (score 0):

When creating new users, you can specify the shell to use with the `-s` option.

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash {username}
```

**Note**: `-m` creates the home directory.

However, if the user already exists, @Nachbars solution is the way to go:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash {username}
```